# proof verification on separable metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,p)$ be metric spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous, if $A\subseteq X$  and $(A,d|_{A})$ is separable show that $$(f(A),p|_{f(A)})$$ is also separable.

Since $f$ is continuous and $A$ is countable then $f(A)$ is countable.
because $\overline{A}= X\Rightarrow B(x,\delta  )\cap X\neq \varnothing (x\in A)$

$\Rightarrow  f(B(x,\delta  ))\cap f(X)\neq \varnothing $ (can i do that?)

$f$ is continuous so $B(f(x),\varepsilon  )\cap Y\neq \varnothing $

Comment: My edit was for a typo: $p|_{f(A)}$ for $d|_{f(A)}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have been trying the same problem because i couldn't solve it in first and know I came up with a different solution which it maybe be correct could someone verify that? Thank you in advance.

Since $A$ is separable $\exists \, X\subset A : \overline{X} = A $ and $X$ is countable $\Rightarrow $ $f=cont$  $f(X)\subset f(A)$ $\Rightarrow $ $\overline{f(X)}\subseteq f(A)$ $ (1)$
it's enough to show $f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(X)}$

Since $\overline{X} = A $ $\Rightarrow  $ $\exists \ : x \in A$ and $x_n \in X : x_n\rightarrow x$ now since $f=cont$  we have that $f(x_n) \in f(X), f(x) \in f(A)$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x) $ with  $f(x_n) \in f(X)$  $\Rightarrow  f(x)\subseteq \overline{f(X)}  \Rightarrow  f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(X)} $ $(2)$ and we prove what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that $A$ is countable: it is separable, so it has a countable dense subset $D$, but it need not itself be countable.

Let $Z=f[A]$; we want to show that $Z$ is separable. Let $E=f[D]$; $E$ is countable, so we’ll be done if we can show that $E$ is dense in $Z$. Let $z\in Z$ and $\epsilon>0$; then $z=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$, and since $f$ is continuous there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f[B(x,\delta)]\subseteq B(z,\epsilon)$. $D$ is dense in $A$, so there is a $p\in D\cap B(x,\delta)$, and clearly $f(p)\in E\cap B(z,\epsilon)$. Thus, $E$ is dense in $Z$, and $Z$ is separable.

Answer (score 0):

$f|_A:A\to f[A]$ is a continuous surjection.

There are many properties that are equivalent to continuity, and some are better tools than others for some problems.

$f:U\to V$ is continuous iff $f(p)\in Cl_V (f[D])$ whenever $D\subseteq U$ and $p\in Cl_U(D).$

So in your Q, let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $A.$ For any $b\in f[A]$ we have $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in A,$ and $a\in Cl_A(D)$. So $b=f(a)\in Cl_{f[A]}(f[D]).$ Therefore $f[D]$ is dense in $f[A].$

Alternatively:

$f:U\to V$ is continuous iff $f[Cl_U(D)]\subseteq Cl_V(f[D])$ for every $D\subseteq U.$

So in your Q, let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $A.$ Then $$f[A]=f[Cl_A(D)]\subseteq Cl_{f[A]}(f[D])\subseteq f[A].$$ So $f[D]$ is dense in $f[A]$ because $Cl_{f[A]}(f[D])=f[A].$